# reinterpret_cast double to char*

Tags: c++, char, double, reinterpret-cast

How can I reinterpret cast from double to char* (I need it to store the data of double in file in bytes). Below is the code and I don't know why it doesn't work:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const double tmpDouble = 1234.;
    char *tmpChar = reinterpret_cast<char*>(tmpDouble);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The question should be "How do I store a `double` as binary data?", but kudos for sneaking it in there. :)

Comment: Try to cast the address of your tmpDouble variable... `&tmpDouble` it points to your bytes.

Comment: @chris How is it `unsigned char *`?

Comment: @0x499602D2, Unless I'm hallucinating, it got changed.

Answer (score 4):

If what you had there worked, it probably wouldn't be what you want - the pointer's value would just be `1234` - effectively pointing to that address which might contain anything (not that it's accessible).

If you just want to have the `double` in binary format, you could do

```
const byte* pDouble = reinterpret_cast<const byte*>(&tmpDouble);
//                                      |
//                             note the address here
```

But first check whatever it is you're using to write to file for a function prototype that takes a `double` directly.

Comment: @DyP missed that, thx.